# What is the right command format for Java ProcessBuilder sudo bash command?

Tags: java, bash, sudo

How to execute a command like this (with sudo) from Java ProcessBuilder? (I do not need to include a password because the normal user has permission to run myscript.log as root without a password.)

```
sudo bash /home/me/path/myscript.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 >> /var/log/path/myscript.log 2>&1
```

My question is how do the elements of this command get passed into the constructor of Java's `ProcessBuilder`?

For example, is "sudo" the first argument to the `ProcessBuilder` ctor, the last, or somewhere else? And how do you know where they go and which elements of the command become arguments to `ProcessBuilder`?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that the redirection does not get executed in the bash command you are invoking.

Try using passing the command to execute as a string usin the -c option for bash:

```
sudo bash -c "/home/me/path/myscript.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 >> /var/log/path/myscript.log 2>&1"
```

In order to use the java ProcessBuilder with this command I would try construct it like this:

```
new ProcessBuilder("sudo", "bash", "-c", "/home/me/path/myscript.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 >> /var/log/path/myscript.log 2>&1");
```

With this use of ProcessBuilder you are basically asking it to execute the command sudo and provide to it 3 parameters. In return sudo will invoke your command like this: `bash -c "..."`.

You might still have a problem when the process will prompt for the sudo password.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command("bash", "-c","sudo su - yoursuperuser -c \"yourcommandorscript\"");
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        showProcess(process);
    

    

    private void showProcess(Process process) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        try {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

            int exitVal = process.waitFor();
            if (exitVal == 0) {
                System.out.println("Success!");
                System.out.println(output);
                System.exit(0);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```